# How to fix unability to save ".eps" file to marklogic database because XDMP-JSONDOC error is thrown?

Tags: configuration, marklogic

I am unable to save file with ".eps" extension to MarkLogic database. Marklogic REST API throws server error with following message: "XDMP-JSONDOC: Document is not JSON". What is important is that I have several instances of database, each on different environment and I am unable to save this file only on one of those instances.

So I assumed that this one instance is configured improperly and found out, that there are differences between four mimetypes returned by `xdmp.mimetypes()` and those shown on mimetypes admin page.

What is more, config for mimetype "application/postscript" returned from `xdmp.mimetypes()` has "*json*" format, and one configured via mimetypes admin page has valid "*binary*" format. I think that this may cause inability to save ".eps" file.

Why do those differences exist and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eps should be binary format.

On my system, the mimetype for eps has:

```
{
"mimetype": "application/postscript", 
"extensions": "ai eps ps", 
"format": "binary"
}
```

If you have a cluster with a mimetype declaration of json for eps, then fix it. Maybe someone changed the format from binary to json, or maybe they added a new mimetype to the cluster config. Inspect the mimetype configs, find the mistake, and correct it.

You can do this via the Admin UI or via API calls to [`admin.mimetype()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin.mimetype), [`admin.mimetypesDelete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin.mimetypesDelete), and [`admin.mimetypesAdd`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin.mimetypesAdd).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have inspected mimetype config using `admin.mimetypesGet` and there is "binary" format specified for "eps" extension. However, when I inspect mimetypes using `xdmp.mimetypes` there is "json" format specified for "eps" extension. I emphasize that there are inconsistencies. And I probably need to configure MarkLogic to return "binary" format for "eps" extension from `xdmp.mimetypes` (in order to make saving "eps" file via "xdmp" work). How can I do this? Using Admin UI doesn't seem to work.

Comment: On the system that is giving you trouble, verify that there aren't multiple mimetype entries that include eps. Run `xdmp.mimetypes().filter(m => String(m.extensions).indexOf("eps") != -1)` and see what comes back. Is there one entry that has json format?

Comment: I have just ran code you have supplied and I can see only one entry. And this one entry has json format.

Comment: So, that explains it. Someone has messed with the mimetypes on that system. If you want it to be treated as binary instead of json, then get rid of that mimetype entry, and put back the original mimetype config for eps (use values that I posted in my answer).

Comment: That is right, deletion of "application/postscript" mimetype entry, and then insertion of this mimetype using `admin.mimetype` functions from query console worked. Now it is possible to add ".eps" document. Thank you for your help.